# How to get IHTMLDocument2 ->get_body ->get_innerHTML into a lowercase string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, string, lowercase

I am trying to get the innerHTML from a webpage body on c++, I have this so far:

```
// I get "Document" from a parameter when calling this code
BSTR bstrContent = NULL;
IHTMLElement *p = 0;
Document->get_body( &p );

if( p )
{
    p->get_innerHTML( &bstrContent );
    p->Release();
}
```

Now I need to turn bstrContent into a lowercase std::string or LPSTR, I've tried this:

```
LPSTR pagecontent = NULL;

int responseLength = (int)wcslen(bstrContent);
pagecontent = new CHAR[ responseLength + 1 ];
wcstombs( pagecontent, bstrContent, responseLength);
```

But "pagecontent" does not always contain the full innerHTML, only a first chunk. I even if it worked, I don't know how to easily make it all lowercase, with a std::string I'd use "transform"+"tolower" to do it.

**So, how can I turn bstrContent into a std::string?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  I don't know of any reason why get_innerHTML would give you an incomplete body, but you can convert a BSTR to a std::string (assuming you don't need to support unicode, in which case you should have been using a std::wstring anyway) using a function found on the following page:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=275978

If you're using ATL there is also the CA2W conversion utility, but the function I linked you to is better since it'll at least support UTF8 if relevant.

Hope that helps,

- Taxilian

Answer (score 0):

std::transform works fine if you have a start-pointer and an end-pointer, too. It works on anything that behaves as sequence iterators (regular pointers qualify).